# Showing a relation is an equivalence relation on $\mathbb {N}$ or $\mathbb {R}$

Tags: equivalence-relations

I have an exercise that consists of 2 parts that I don't really know how to prove.

Consider the relation $\mathcal R$ on $\mathbb {N}$ defined as follows: for all $a, b$ ∈ $\mathbb {N}$, a$\mathcal R$b if
there exist $m, n$ ∈ $\mathbb {N}$\{0} such that $am^2$ = $bn^2$
. Show that $\mathcal R$ is an equivalence relation. Show that the set $\mathbb {N}$/$\mathcal R$ is infinite.

Consider the relation $\mathcal Q$ on $\mathbb {R}$ defined as follows: for all $x, y$ ∈ $\mathbb {R}$, x$\mathcal Q$y if there exist $r$ ∈  $\mathbb {R}$\{0} such that $x = yr^2$
. Show that $\mathcal Q$ is an equivalence relation. How many elements are there in $\mathbb {R}$/$\mathcal Q$?

So I've been reading my script and I know that an equivalence relation is a relation that is reflexive, symmetric and transitive. For the first task, it seems somewhat intuitive that this is an equivalence relation. But I'm struggling with proving this mathematically correct.

Comment: Reflexivity and symmetry are straightforward. Prove transitivity.

Comment: @Berci I thought symmetry and reflexivity were straightforward. I've seen the proofs for some examples. I just never know if it's "enough" sometimes since I don't think I'm really proving anything most of the time, just rearranging some variables.

Comment: Yes, often rearranging the variables and exchanging the two sides of an equation does give a valid proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $a \cdot 1^2 = a \cdot 1^2$, so $a \mathcal R a$.

If $a \mathcal R b$, then $\exists m, n \in \Bbb N$ such that $am^2=bn^2$, so $bn^2 = am^2$ and $b \mathcal R a$.

If $a \mathcal R b, b \mathcal R c$, then $\exists m, n, k, t \in \Bbb N$ such that $am^2=bn^2, bk^2=ct^2$, so $a(mk)^2=b(nk)^2 = c(nt)^2$ and $a \mathcal R c$.

Note that if  $p, q$ are distinct primes, $pm^2 = qn^2$ is not possible (because an odd power of $p$ divides the left-hand side but an even power of $p$ divides the right-hand side), so $\mathcal R$ has infinitely many different equivalence classes.

A similar proof shows that $\mathcal Q$ is an equivalence relation on $\Bbb R$.  Any positive number is a square in $\Bbb R$, so $x \mathcal Q y \iff x \text{ and } y \text{ have the same sign}$ and $\mathcal Q$ has three equivalence classes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! That helped a lot! Just a quick question about the second exercise. What do you mean with Q having three equivalence classes?

Comment: Note that $e \mathcal Q \pi$ because $e(\sqrt{\frac {\pi}{e}})^2=\pi$.  Does that help you see when two real numbers are $\mathcal Q$-equivalent to one another?

Comment: So since they cancel out , this works for any real number in $\mathbb {R}$

Comment: @23408924 Try it for $e$ and $- \pi$.